# How to start nodejs in background and restart all 10 minutes

Tags: node.js, debian, debian-based

^Topic

I have Debian 8 now.

I have 2 node files I want run this 2 files together

Program 1 should start nodejs /home/Bots/server/server.js
after this I need a timeout from 10 sec. 
Programm 2 should start after 10 secounds when program 1 started. nodejs /home/Bots/f.js

Thanks

I found here nothing what work :/

Comment: It's probably going to be more reliable to make your bot handle a down server and poll until it is up rather than trying to orchestrate processes in a specific order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume your `java` tag should be `javascript` since it looks like you're talking about nodejs.

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but you can launch new processes from within nodejs using the child process module with either `.exec()` or `.spawn()`.

So, if you have one nodejs process running already, you can use `setTimeout()` and the child process module to launch another process at some future scheduled time.

For example, here's an example from the child_process doc pages wrapped inside a `setTimeout()`:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

setTimeout(function() {
    const child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
    });        

}, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: thanks now I need a start script :) but I must start putty and when I close it then my nodejs close :s

Comment: @CCSESD - It looks like you aren't running a current version of node.js that supports arrow functions.  You can change the above code to use older style function callbacks or upgrade to a newer version of nodejs.